# Cocoapods installation error in terminal

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

While trying to install cocoapods I'm getting the following error, can any one help me debug it?

```
MacBook-Pro:~ saiteja$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
MacBook-Pro:~ saiteja$
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

First install an old version of 'activesupport' (which is both compatible with ruby 2.0 and with cocoapods) and then install cocoapods. 
$ sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

This was issue exactly faced by me. 
First you need install active script :

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```